# How can I disable web support in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I recently ran this command to try web support out in Flutter:

```
flutter config --enable-web
```

Now, every project I make has a `web` folder and inside is an `index.html`. Is there any way I can disable that for future projects and is it safe for me to just delete the folder and carry on?

Comment: is it safe to delete the folder?

Comment: @Nuqo yes, Its possible and safe to delete the folder manually for existing projects, since the folder doesn't have any dependencies.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

```
flutter config --no-enable-web
```

if you try to type `flutter config` in terminal you will see all options

Comment: But when i enabled it, it changed my project so i get things like "Plugin project :firebase_auth_web not found. Please update settings.gradle.".. How do i fix this?

Comment: I wonder who made the decision to call this `--no-enable` instead of `disable`

Comment: @JoãoAbrantes probably used as negation. `--no` could be used to negate many other commands, instead of creating new counter commands for each one of those e.g. `disable` for `enable`

Comment: Can this be done per project?