# Flutter doctor finds an unknown connected device

Tags: flutter

I restarted OS and right after that this command was executed

```
$ flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.2, on Microsoft Windows ...)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
[√] VS Code (version 1.54.2)
[√] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!\
```

For some reason it detects a connected device. How to find it and how to delete it?

Comment: what is the output of `flutter devices`?

Comment: @BijayRegmi 1 connected device: Chrome (web) • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 89.0.4389.90. So it is Chrome detected as connected...

Comment: Flutter can target web as well. So it's considering chrome browser as a target device. If you don't want to target web just run `flutter config --no-enable-web`. But given this situation, I wouldn't bother much. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58463079/how-can-i-disable-web-support-in-flutter